# Dominated convergence theorem query

Tags: functional-analysis

Why is the hypothesis that the sequence $(f_{n})$ is dominated required? If $f_{n} \to f$ pointwise, then $f_{n}-f$ is bounded and tends to 0 so applying the theorem to $f_{n}-f$ gives the desired conclusion, and it is not necessary that $f_{n}$ is dominated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of functions $$f_n = \frac{1}{x} \chi_{(1/n, 1)}(x)$$ converges to $1/x$ pointwise, but the differences $f - f_n$ aren't bounded for *any* $n$. And although every $f_n \in L^1$, the limit function is not integrable.

---

Alternatively, the functions $$g_n = n \chi_{(0, 1/n)}$$

are all in $L^1$, and converge to $0$ pointwise everywhere. But $$\lim_n \int g_n = 1 \ne 0 = \int \lim_n g_n$$ There is no $L^1$ dominating function for all $g_n$.